# why is codeigniters raw_input_stream null?

Tags: codeigniter

I was wondering why is the raw_input_stream returning null. Here is my ajax call that I do from UI5.

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/CI/controllername/functionname",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(oParameters),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    MessageToast.show(data);
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    MessageToast.show(e.status);
                }
            });
```

Here is my controller

```
class controllername extends CI_Controller
{
    public function functionname()
    {
        echo $this->input->raw_input_stream;
        if ($this->input->raw_input_stream == null) echo "null";
    }
}
```

When I run this code raw_input_stream is null. Not sure why. I check the request payload on chrome developer tools and the data is send. Here is request payload.

[image]

Comment: what says console.dir(data) right after the ajax success function?

Comment: As you are using post would it not be better to use `$this->input->post()` ? Try `print_r($_POST)` and see what output appears in the Chrome console response.

Comment: I printed the $_POST array and it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Following:

```
parse_str(urldecode($this->input->raw_input_stream), $output);
$data = $output;
```

This may help.